# VHDL - same bitstream, two boards -> inout issue

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I wanted to ask if it is possible to use an inout pin as inout and normal out? The two behaviours should be switched through a MUX. The reason for this weird looking implementation is that I have two boards and I want to use the same bitstream. On one board, the same pin is connected to a LED through GPIO and on the other it goes to my I2C bus connection. The software tries to detect the I2C and if successful it sets a register. If not, it clears it.

```
LED_or_SDA      : inout std_logic; -- port definition

process (register)
begin
   if ( register = '1') then -- software sets this register
       LED_or_SDA <= I2C_SDA; -- here I want to use it as inout
   else
       LED_or_SDA <= gpio_reg; -- here I want to use it as normal out
   end if;
end process;
```

This implementation throws the error "bidirect pad net is driving non-buffer primitives" during translate. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.  A mux is not a switch, it is a logic function.  The line

```
LED_or_SDA <= I2C_SDA;
```

strongly drives `LED_or_SDA` from `I2C_SDA`.  It does not connect the two nets in a way that allows bidirectional data flow.

You'll need to separate the two directions:

```
I2C_SDA_in <= LED_or_SDA;
LED_or_SDA <= gpio_reg WHEN (register = '1') ELSE
              '0' WHEN (I2C_SDA_out = '0') ELSE
              'Z';
```

Most I2C logic blocks have separate data in and out signals anyway, right up until the external interface, where you'll find a tri-state buffer expressed in much the same way as the code I gave you.  You'll simply need to make the input and output data separate ports on your I2C block.

Unfortunately, the weak drive state of the internal signal likely *isn't* accessible to internal logic, so these **won't work**:

```
LED_or_SDA <= gpio_reg WHEN (register = '1') ELSE
              I2C_SDA_out;

LED_or_SDA <= gpio_reg WHEN (register = '1') ELSE
              'Z' WHEN (I2C_SDA_out = 'Z') ELSE
              I2C_SDA_out;
```

The VHDL compiler actually is keeping track of a tri-state control signal, and propagating that through port statements until it hits the external pin and connects it to the real (hardware) tri-state buffer.  But in most compilers you can't access that control signal for your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your error message I assume that we are talking about a Xilinx System, e.g. around a Microblaze - if that's not the case, please update your question and also specify the exact GPIO core you're using.

Often these GPIO blocks already contain the IO-Buffer macro by default. This IOBUF is located next to a physical pin and can not drive any other signals on the FPGA. Hence the GPIO block is intended to be used on the top level of the chip and be directly connected to a pin. However, there usually is a way to also access the signals before the IOBUF: E.g. in Xilinx Platform Studio on the tab "Ports" you should have a choice to use also `GPIO_IO` (after buffer), `GPIO_IO_I` (pure input), `GPIO_IO_O` (pure output), `GPIO_IO_T` (tristate) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the trick is to treat it always as a tristate buffer, and control the output based on the state of register

```
-- define a tristate pin the usual way.

LED_or_SDA <= LED_or_SDA_out when LED_or_SDA_tristate = '0' else 'Z';
LED_or_SDA_in <= LED_or_SDA

-- then control the data onto it, and the tristate control line

LED_or_SDA_tristate <= '0' when register = '0' else ICD_SDA;
LED_or_SDA_out <= gpio_reg when register = '0' else '0';
```